# getting error on magento 1.9 search

Tags: magento-1.9

There has been an error processing your request
The attribute model is not defined

```
Trace:
#0 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(239): Mage::throwException('The attribute m...')
#1 /Data/furny/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(66): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getAttributeModel()
#2 /Data/furny/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php(265): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->_getItemsData()
#3 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute->_initItems()
#4 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#5 /Data/furny/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Block/Filter.php(88): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#6 /Data/furny/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/manapro/filterpositioning/horizontal/view.phtml(78): Mana_Filters_Block_Filter->getItemsCount()
#7 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Data/furny/app...')
#8 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#9 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#12 /Data/furny/app/code/local/Mana/Core/Block/List.php(17): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#13 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mana_Core_Block_List->_toHtml()
#14 /Data/furny/app/code/local/ManaPro/FilterPositioning/Model/Observer.php(216): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): ManaPro_FilterPositioning_Model_Observer->renderLayeredNavigationAboveProductList(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(ManaPro_FilterPositioning_Model_Observer), 'renderLayeredNa...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 /Data/furny/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#18 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(943): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#19 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('search_result_l...', true)
#21 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php(161): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('search_result_l...')
#22 /Data/furny/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml(42): Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result->getProductListHtml()
#23 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Data/furny/app...')
#24 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#25 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#26 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#28 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#29 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#31 /Data/furny/app/design/frontend/default/blank/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(21): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#32 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Data/furny/app...')
#33 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#34 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#35 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(80): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#40 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 /Data/furny/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 /Data/furny/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 /Data/furny/index.php(83): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#45 {main}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using third party extension. Disable manapro or any other search related extension and check again.

Comment: yes, but suddenly it look like this error before it was work fine..

Comment: is there any one who can help me to solve this. i need help to solve this